# How to add execution time taken for an API to respond in the JSON response - Python with flask

Tags: python, flask

How to add execution time taken for an API to respond the JSON response

```
I would like to add the time taken by the API to respond in the response JSON. Currently calling an API using python with flask

If anyone can guide with best approach.

Note:I have updated the question
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `requests` library, the `Response` object returns with an `elapsed` property.
This property gives you the time delta between the request and response.
For example:

```
res = requests.get(url)
print(res.elapsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using `python decorators`

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask, request
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

def calculate_time(func):
    """Print the execution time of the decorated function and add execution time in response"""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper_timer(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        response = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        print(f"Execution finished in {run_time} secs")
        response["time_taken"] = run_time
        return response
    return wrapper_timer

@timer
@app.route('/login', methods=["POST"])
def login():
    ......

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The reason for using decorators is that you can compute the execution time of any function

```
@timer
def any_function():
    .....
```